# Tribonacci function in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Is there a different,cleaner way of generating tribonacci?

```
(defn tribonacci [x](last (reduce
      (fn  [[a b c] n]
          (conj [b c] (+ a b c))) [0 0 1] (range (- x 3)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write it:

```
(defn tribonacci [a b c]
  (lazy-seq (cons a (tribonacci b c (+' a b c)))))
```

If you want to get the *n*th tribonacci number, just use, for instance, `(tribonacci 0 0 1)` and then call `nth` on that.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a lazy sequence of these numbers, and take the needed element from it:

```
user> (def t (lazy-cat [1 1 2] (map +' t (rest t) (nthrest t 2))))
#'user/t
user> (take 20 t)
(1 1 2 4 7 13 24 44 81 149 274 504 927 1705 3136 5768 10609 19513 35890 66012)
```

replace `[1 1 2]` to `[0 1 1]`, if you need them starting from `0`

Comment: This is a bad idea, Once you realize some elements of `t`, those elements will not be garbage collected because the var holds onto the head of the sequence.

Comment: yeah i know, just wanted to show the magic of lazy sequences. (well since the question was "is there another way", guess it is possible answer